# Wiring into lamppost - how to make it watertight

Tags: wiring, installation, cable-management

I am planning to install an LTE antenna and camera on a lampost. The lampost is galvanised steel. I want to pass the cable(s) about 4m up through the 7m sidewall.

How would I best make the hole watertight? My options as I see them are:

1. Rubber grommet (this would likely be easiest to install, but may not be watertight?)
2. Cable gland (it would be difficult to put the inside piece - maybe I could pull it up from the inside with a string? How would I tighten it thereafter?)

Anyone tried this? What approach would you use? Although I prefer the cable gland approach, I am hesitant to try it without guidance as the hole would be bigger, and i may not get a grommet to then fit if it doesnt work out...

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for complete waterproof, or just as water resistant as you can get it? It might be that a rubber grommet would be sufficient. It's likely that the entire post is going to be considered a wet location and that all connections within it would be expected to be wet and require appropriate cabling. Also, just to be sure, it's 4 _meters_ up a 7 _meter_ pole (~12 feet and 21 feet for those of us on Imperial units)?

Comment: Find a tight fitting grommet and/or use some silicone.  Your primary goal should be to protect the cable from the sharp edges of the pole holes, and to make it look good.  If you keep water out that's nice but there will be condensation inside the pole so the pole needs to drain and you need to use outdoor rated cables.  Having done that, it doesn't matter if a little water enters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lamp post is essentially a vertical stick of conduit, located outside, and all outside conduit is **defined** as a **wet** location.

Which basically means, do what you like, there **will** be water. All connections inside the lamp post should be done in a manner that will tolerate being wet, because they will be wet.

My primary advice on *limiting* direct water ingress at the cable entry is to use a **drip loop** so that any water running down or along the cable drips off, rather than impacting the point where it goes into the lamp-post. That's a loop of cable that goes downwards from the entry point, and water runs down it and drips off the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I would fit the gland **before** mounting the lamppost upright.

Then you can hold the gland on the end of a pole to slide it into position and tighten it easily. You can even fit the cable ready.

Did the equivalent for water butt connections (made from those blue chemical drums) as their positioning meant my arms were too short.